# How to generate JSON with nested elements from MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, mysql-json

I have table like this:

```
 +----+-------+-------+--------------+ 
 | id | title | city  | street       |  
 +----+-------+-------+--------------+ 
 | 1  | First | London|  Oxford      |
 +----+-------+-------+--------------+ 
 |  2 | Second| Berlin| Nievenheimer |      
 +----+-------+-------+--------------+
```

Is here a way to write **MySql** query which will generate JSON output with nested elements. Similar like this:

```
{
  1: {
    "title": "First",
    "address": {
      "city": "London",
      "street": "Oxford"
    }
  },
  2: {
    "title": "Second",
    "address": {
      "city": "Berlin",
      "street": "Nievenheimer"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not post TEXT, when the image only contains text?

Comment: @Luuk I tried, but it after paste it was disorganized.

Comment: i do not see any disorganized things .... (see the edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use json generation functions:

```
select json_object_agg(
    id,
    json_object(
        'title',   title,
        'address', json_object('city', city, 'street', street)
    )
) res
from mytable
```